# How do I take the inner product of these two tensors: $T^{ij}$ and $T_{ij}$

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products

The tensors are of contravariant and covariant order two, respectively. Our teacher said something about the result being identity, or the kroneker delta $\delta_i^j$, I think, but I'm not too sure. I'd like someone to please explain the process of taking the inner product in this case. Thanks.

Comment: $T^{ik} T_{kj} = \delta^i_j$

Comment: It depends on how you're defining $T^{ij}$ and $T_{ij}$. If, as is usually the case, one of these is obtained from the other by raising (or lowering) indices, then the answer is $\|T\|^2$. But if $T_{ij}$ is meant to be a nondegenerate quadratic form on a vector space $V$ and $T^{ij}$ represents the dual form on $V^*$ induced by means of the isomorphism $x\mapsto T(x,\cdot)$, then $T^{ij}$ and $T_{ij}$ are inverse matrices, and then $T^{ik}T_{kj}=\delta^i_j$, and $T^{ij}T_{ij}$ is equal to the dimension of $V$.